# Laravel 5.4 Vue.JS Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Starting with Vue.js and wanted to give it a try to the example that comes with laravel.

No component is displayed and in console I get

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Example>
   <Root>
```

Not a fresh install, upgraded from 5.2->5.3->5.4

resources/assets/js/app.js

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

resources/assets/js/components/Example.vue

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    I'm an example component!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is the blade in which I have the js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
        <example></example>
    </div>
        <script src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: do you have laravel mixx here? can you show webpack.mix.js ?(in root)

Comment: Yes, I do have laravel mix and added webpack to the post.

Comment: another thing, maybe compare your package json with source one - especially the vue version https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/package.json

Comment: how about vuejs versions?have you checked already?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has to do with the way you are mounting Vue. One time it needs compiler and another time not https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only .

You could try my way (it is pure vue project, made from vue webpack template):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import Example from './components/Example'
import router from './router' //this will import router/index.js

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App, Example }
})
```

This will mount component in global object.

Comment: And in this case I would need the runtime only? from the link how would it adapt to what I'm doing or would I need to change the structure

Comment: does putting this inside main.js returns any error?

Comment: It worked, just adapting it to mine, just was wondering it is a runtime+compiler build then?

Comment: mine requires compiler, it hasn't render function inside Vue object. I'm quite new to Vue :)

Comment: Thanks also. Good luck!

Answer (score 51):

It should be `require('./components/Example.vue').default`. Since v13, `vue-loader` exports the component as the default key, which still works the same when using `import`, but requires the above when using `require`.

Comment: To clarify the above answer, this resolved an issue I was having where I had additional vue dependencies in package.json, including vue-loader (14.1.1) and vue-template-compiler (2.5.13) as well as vue 2.5.13.  Adding .default to the require line in app.js got rid of the error in the console and allowed the component to function.  Removing the additional dependencies also seems to resolve the issue, so it's not purely vue 2.5.13 causing the issue (this seemed a bit unclear in the original answer).  If you need said dependencies, this does the trick!

Comment: Same principle I believe as @clusterBuddy answer for components in app.js as `Vue.component('form-component', require('./components/FormComponent').default);`

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, it worked for me but one thing is confusing me why it is working in other project which doesn't have `.default` after require?

Comment: @HaritsinhGohil check vue-loader version

Answer (score 17):

Try this

```
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
```

Comment: addition of `.default` at the end of component did the trick in laravel app. thanks

Comment: try this but not load component.

Answer (score 12):

As of now, the plaster I have is to  add a 'default()' to all Vue object's component.

```
Vue.component('form-component', require('./components/FormComponent').default);
Vue.component('gratitude-pop', require('./components/GratitudePop').default);//..etc..etc
```

Running this package:

```
  "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vuex": "^3.0.1"
    }
```

> Throw in your thumbs-up for using VUEX ;P

Comment: I have no idea why this works, but it did.  Thank you!  I only had to add "default" to a single component, which was my parent.  Also, this error only came about when I updated dependencies in webpack, particularly "laravel-mix": "^4.0.13" just now.  Some new requirement?

Answer (score 9):

I have resolved this issue easily by using 
**.default** method at the end of the 
**`require().default`** in the following line.

```
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('articles', require('./components/ArticleComponent.vue').default);
```

> app.js

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('articles', require('./components/ArticleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app', 
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
Vue.component('example', require ('./components/Example.vue'));
```

Use this

```
Vue.component ('example', require ('./components/Example.vue').default);
```

Comment: .default has do be lower case. And without space before the dot.

Answer (score 0):

- delete the folder node_modules
- run npm install
- add the following line to package.json

  ```
  "webpack": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  ```
- npm run webpack
- npm run watch
- dont change anything else

Comment: This not working, only works after adding .default at the end of require()

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a small piece of information on top of the above answers.

The error is fixed if **.default** is added on the component that throws the error.